# Dataframe becoming empty after calling a method in DataWriter class that deletes records from delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

How can I prevent the dataframe `data` from becoming empty after calling the `delete_processed_data()` method in my DataWriter class that also has a `register_processed_data()` method which inserts data into a delta table?
I'm not overwriting the dataframe and it's only being used as a condition to check if it has any data with a count.

Here's my complete code (*databricks notebook*):

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd
from dn.utils import table
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
import pytz
import calendar

list_countries = (
    table.get_silver_table(table_name='stpos_dim_itemticket')
    .select('pais')
    .distinct()
)

list_countries = [row.pais for row in list_countries.collect()]
# Include "Todos" option
list_countries.insert(0, 'Todos')

dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
dbutils.widgets.text(name='category', defaultValue='Todos', label='Categoria')
dbutils.widgets.text(name='today', defaultValue=str(date.today()), label='Fecha proceso')
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="country", defaultValue='Todos', choices=list_countries, label="Pais")
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name='forced_load', defaultValue='no', choices=['si', 'no'], label='Forzar carga')
dbutils.widgets.dropdown(name="reprocessing", defaultValue='si', choices=['si', 'no'], label="Reproceso")
country = dbutils.widgets.get('country').strip()
category = dbutils.widgets.get("category").strip()
today = datetime.strptime(dbutils.widgets.get('today').strip(), '%Y-%m-%d')
wave_date = today.replace(day=1)
forced_load = dbutils.widgets.get('forced_load').strip()
reprocessing = dbutils.widgets.get('reprocessing').lower().strip()
print(f"Categoria: {category}")
print(f"Fecha proceso: {today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")
print(f"Pais: {country}")
print(f"Forzar carga: {forced_load}")
print(f'Reproceso: {reprocessing}')
print(f"Fecha ola: {wave_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")

class DataExtractor():
    def __init__(self, category, today, country, list_countries, wave_date, reprocessing, forced_load):
        self.category = category
        self.today = today
        self.country = country
        self.list_countries = list_countries
        self.wave_date = wave_date
        self.reprocessing = reprocessing
        self.forced_load = forced_load
        
        if self.reprocessing == 'no' or self.forced_load == 'si':
            self.days_for_wave = self.get_days_for_wave()
            
        if self.country.lower() == 'todos':
            self.country_condition = "lower(pais) = lower(pais)"
        else:
            self.country_condition = f"lower(pais) = lower('{country}')"

        if self.category.lower() == 'todos':
            self.category_condition = "lower(categoria) = lower(categoria)"
        else:
            self.category_condition = f"lower(categoria) = lower('{category}')"

    def get_days_for_wave_by_country(self, country, path_file):      
        days_for_wave = (
            spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load(path_file)
            .where(f"fecha_ola = '{self.wave_date}'")
            .where(f"lower(pais) = lower('{country}')")
            .selectExpr(
                "fecha_ola",
                "to_date(fecha) as fecha_transaccion",
                "pais")
        )
        
        if days_for_wave.count() == 0:
            # Año y mes deseado
            year = self.wave_date.year
            month = self.wave_date.month

            # Obtener el número de días en el mes especificado
            _, num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)

            # Crear una lista con todos los días del mes
            days = [(date(year, month, day),) for day in range(1, num_days+1)]

            # Convertir cada fecha a una cadena de texto
            days_str = [(day[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),) for day in days]

            # Convert list to dataframe
            days_for_wave = (
                spark.createDataFrame(days_str)
                .withColumnRenamed("_1", "fecha_transaccion")
                .withColumn("fecha_ola", F.lit(self.wave_date))
                .withColumn("pais", F.lit(country))
                .selectExpr(
                    "fecha_ola",
                    "to_date(fecha_transaccion) AS fecha_transaccion",
                    "pais")                
            )

        print(f"Loaded {days_for_wave.count()} days for wave {self.wave_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} and country {country}")
        return days_for_wave

    def get_days_for_wave(self):
        """
        Get the days for the wave
        """
        # Load dim_dia_ola.xlsx with wave definition
        path_file = "dbfs:/mnt/storetrack/transitraw/dichterneira/storelive/dim_dia_ola.xlsx"
        print(f'Loading days for wave from file: {path_file}...')
        
        if self.country.lower() == 'todos':
            # Get list of countries (excluding 'Todos')
            list_of_countries = self.list_countries[1:]
        else:
            list_of_countries = [self.country]
        
        schema = StructType([
            StructField("fecha_ola", TimestampType(), nullable=True),
            StructField("fecha_transaccion", DateType(), nullable=True),
            StructField("pais", StringType(), nullable=True)
        ])

        # Crear un DataFrame vacío con el esquema especificado
        days_for_wave = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=schema)        

        for country in list_of_countries:
            days_for_wave_by_country = self.get_days_for_wave_by_country(country, path_file)
            max_day_of_wave = days_for_wave_by_country.agg(F.max("fecha_transaccion")).collect()[0][0]
            if self.today.date() > max_day_of_wave and self.forced_load == 'no':
                print(f"Today {self.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} is not included in wave days for country {country} and wave {self.wave_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")
            else:
                if country == list_of_countries[0]:
                    days_for_wave = days_for_wave_by_country
                else:
                    days_for_wave = days_for_wave.union(days_for_wave_by_country)
                
        return days_for_wave       

    def get_data_items(self):
        """
        Filter sales by category, wave and country
        """
        if self.reprocessing == 'si' and self.forced_load == 'no':
            sales_filtered = (
                table.get_silver_table(table_name='sl_fact_item_ticket')
                .where(f"fecha_ola = '{self.wave_date}'")
                .where(self.country_condition)
                .where(self.category_condition)                 
            )
        else:
            sales_filtered = (
                table.get_silver_table(table_name='stpos_dim_itemticket')
                .drop("fecha_ola")
                .where(self.country_condition)
                .where(self.category_condition)
                .selectExpr("*", "to_date(date) as fecha_transaccion")
                .join(self.days_for_wave, ["fecha_transaccion", "pais"], how="inner")
                .drop("fecha_transaccion")            
            )
        print(f"{sales_filtered.count()} items loaded. [Get data items]")
        return sales_filtered
      
    def get_product_catalog(self):
        product_catalog = (
            table.get_bronze_table(table_name='brz_catalogo_productos', module_name='catalogo')
            .where(self.country_condition)
            .selectExpr(
                "upc as barcode",
                "pais",
                "categoria", 
                "marca", 
                "submarca", 
                "fabricante", 
                """CASE WHEN lower(split(contenido, ' ')[1]) = 'ml' THEN 'L'
                        WHEN lower(split(contenido, ' ')[1]) = 'gr' THEN 'Kg'
                        WHEN lower(split(contenido, ' ')[1]) = 'und' THEN 'Und'
                      END AS unidad_std""", 
                "conversion AS contenido_std", 
                "split(contenido, ' ')[0] AS contenido", 
                "split(contenido, ' ')[1] AS unidad_medida", 
                "idref AS id_ref"
            )
        )
        
        return product_catalog

class DataEnricher():
    def __init__(self, reprocessing, forced_load):
        self.reprocessing = reprocessing
        self.forced_load = forced_load
    
    def rename_fields(self, df_item):
        if self.reprocessing == 'no' or self.forced_load == 'si':
            print("Renaming fields...")
            df_item = (
                df_item
                .selectExpr(
                    'CAST(fecha_ola AS DATE) AS fecha_ola',
                    'pdv AS nombre_pdv',
                    'marca',
                    'submarca',
                    'pais',
                    'contenido',
                    'unidad_medida',
                    'CAST(cantidad AS DOUBLE) as cantidad',
                    'CAST(precio_local AS DOUBLE) as precio_local',
                    'barcode',
                    'date AS fecha_transaccion',
                    'categoria',
                    'categoria_name',
                    'descripcion',
                    'id_ref',
                    'posdb_id',
                    'id_ticket',
                    'id_item',
                    'id_pdv',
                    'venta_usd',
                    'venta_local',
                    'precio_usd',
                    'id_canasto'
                )
            )
        
        return df_item
    
    def calculate_standard_fields(self, df_item):
        if self.reprocessing == 'no' or self.forced_load == 'si':
            print("Caculating standard fields...")
            df_item = (
                df_item
                # Add column with converted Ml to L and Gr to Kg
                .withColumn("contenido_std", 
                            F.when(F.col("unidad_medida") == "Ml", F.col("contenido") / 1000)
                            .when(F.col("unidad_medida") == "Gr", F.col("contenido")/1000)
                            .otherwise(F.col("contenido")))
                .withColumn("unidad_std",
                            F.when(F.col("unidad_medida") == "Ml", F.lit("L"))
                            .when(F.col("unidad_medida") == "Gr", F.lit("Kg")))
            )
        
        return df_item
    
    def calculate_fields(self, df_items):
        """
        Set the time zone of the dataframe
        """
        if self.reprocessing == 'no' or self.forced_load == 'si':
            print("Calulating time zone field...")
            # Create dataframe with the time zone
            time_zone = [(1, '05:00:00', '09:59:59'),
                (2, '10:00:00', '13:59:59'),
                (3, '14:00:00', '19:59:59'),
                (4, '20:00:00', '23:59:59'),
                (4, '00:00:00', '04:59:59')]
            time_zone = spark.createDataFrame(time_zone, ['id_franja', 'inicio', 'fin'])
            # Convert inicio and fin to datetime
            time_zone = (
                time_zone
                .withColumn("inicio", F.to_timestamp(F.col("inicio"), "HH:mm:ss"))
                .withColumn("fin", F.to_timestamp(F.col("fin"), "HH:mm:ss"))
            )
            df_items = (
                df_items
                .withColumn("hora_transaccion", F.substring(F.col("fecha_transaccion"), 12, 8))
                .withColumn("hora_transaccion", F.to_timestamp(F.col("hora_transaccion"), "HH:mm:ss"))
                .join(time_zone, on=F.col("hora_transaccion").between(F.col("inicio"), F.col("fin")), how="left")
                .drop("hora_transaccion", "inicio", "fin")
            )
        
        return df_items
      
    def update_product_features(self, data, product_catalog):        
        if data.count() > 0:
            print("Updating fields from brz_catalogo_productos")

            data = (
              data
              .drop("categoria", "marca", "submarca", "fabricante", "unidad_std", "contenido_std", "contenido", "unidad_medida", "id_ref")
              .join(product_catalog, on=["barcode", "pais"], how="left")
            )
            
        return data          
    
class DataWriter():
    def __init__(self, wave_date, country, category):
        self.wave_date = wave_date
        self.country = country
        self.category = category
        
        if self.country.lower() == 'todos':
            self.country_condition = "lower(pais) = lower(pais)"
        else:
            self.country_condition = f"lower(pais) = lower('{country}')"

        if self.category.lower() == 'todos':
            self.category_condition = "lower(categoria) = lower(categoria)"
        else:
            self.category_condition = f"lower(categoria) = lower('{category}')"
    
    def delete_processed_data(self, datos):
        df_categoria_activa = (
            table.get_bronze_table(
                table_name='sl_configuracion_procesamiento_zona_silver', 
                module_name='storetrack'
            )
            .where(f"fecha_ola = '{wave_date}' and lower(trim(procesar)) = 'si'")
            .where(self.country_condition)
            .where(self.category_condition)
            .selectExpr(
                "categoria",
                "pais",
                "fecha_ola"
            )            
        )
        
        if datos.count() > 0:
            display(datos.where("categoria = 'Galletas dulces'"))            
            table_path = table.get_silver_table_path(table_name="sl_fact_item_ticket")
            deltaTableToWrite = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, table_path)
            print("Deleting old rows...")
            deltaTableToWrite.alias('current')\
                .merge(
                    df_categoria_activa.alias('delete'),
                    'current.pais = delete.pais AND current.categoria = delete.categoria AND current.fecha_ola = delete.fecha_ola')\
                .whenMatchedDelete()\
                .execute()

            display(datos.where("categoria = 'Galletas dulces'"))  
            
            
    def register_processed_data(self, data):
        if data.count() > 0:
            print("Inserting new rows...")
            display(data.where("categoria = 'Galletas dulces'"))
            table_path = table.get_silver_table_path(table_name="sl_fact_item_ticket")
            deltaTableToWrite = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, table_path)
            
            deltaTableToWrite.alias('current')\
                .merge(
                    data.alias('new'),
                    'current.id_item = new.id_item AND current.fecha_ola = new.fecha_ola')\
                .whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
                    {
                        "fecha_ola": "new.fecha_ola",
                        "marca": "new.marca",
                        "submarca": "new.submarca",
                        "pais": "new.pais",
                        "contenido": "new.contenido",
                        "unidad_medida": "new.unidad_medida",
                        "cantidad": "new.cantidad",
                        "precio_local": "new.precio_local",
                        "barcode": "new.barcode",
                        "fecha_transaccion": "new.fecha_transaccion",
                        "categoria": "new.categoria",
                        "categoria_name": "new.categoria_name",
                        "descripcion": "new.descripcion",
                        "id_ref": "new.id_ref",
                        "posdb_id": "new.posdb_id",
                        "id_ticket": "new.id_ticket",
                        "id_item": "new.id_item",
                        "id_pdv": "new.id_pdv",
                        "venta_usd": "new.venta_usd",
                        "venta_local": "new.venta_local",
                        "precio_usd": "new.precio_usd",
                        "nombre_pdv": "new.nombre_pdv",
                        "contenido_std": "new.contenido_std",
                        "unidad_std": "new.unidad_std",
                        "id_canasto": "new.id_canasto",
                        "id_franja": "new.id_franja"
                    }
                )\
                .execute()
            display(data.where("categoria = 'Galletas dulces'"))
            print(f"{data.count()} items loaded. [Write processed data]")
                    
        else:
            print("No data to save in silver.sl_fact_item_ticket")
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_extractor = DataExtractor(category, today, country, list_countries, wave_date, reprocessing, forced_load)
    data = data_extractor.get_data_items()
    product_catalog = data_extractor.get_product_catalog()

    cleaner = DataCleaner(wave_date, country, category, reprocessing, forced_load)
    data = cleaner.clean_data(data)

    data_enricher = DataEnricher(reprocessing, forced_load)
    data = data_enricher.rename_fields(data)
    data = data_enricher.calculate_standard_fields(data)
    data = data_enricher.calculate_fields(data)    
    data = data_enricher.update_product_features(data, product_catalog)

    data_write = DataWriter(wave_date, country, category)
    data_write.delete_processed_data(data)
    data_write.register_processed_data(data)
```

The parameters with which I am running the notebook are:

```
Categoria: Todos
Fecha proceso: 2022-12-01
Pais: Todos
Forzar carga: no
Reproceso: si
Fecha ola: 2022-12-01
```

The following output is displayed:

```
993313 items loaded. [Get data items]
62023 items loaded. [Remove blocked categories]
Updating fields from brz_catalogo_productos
[DISLPLAY ROWS DATAFRAME data]
Deleting old rows...
Query returned no results
No data to save in silver.sl_fact_item_ticket
```